# Changing the page layout and canvas size in LibreOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice-draw

This is probably a simple question, but I don't can't find how to change the page layout (e.g. horizontal vs vertical) or the canvas size in LibreOffice Draw. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the menu Format/Page dialog to configure the size and orientation of the canvas.

Updating this old answer, the location changed in newer versions of LibreOffice, using v6.4.7.2 this option is under Menu-> Page/Properties

Comment: I don't see "Page" under "Format" https://imgur.com/ZGAkFMx.png

Comment: Updating this old answer, the location changed in newer versions of LibreOffice, using v6.4.7.2 this option is under Menu-> Page/Properties

Answer (score 3):

`MenuBar`->`Format`->`Page/Slide properties...`

I suggest changing to screen orientation and playing with the size to get plenty of room for creative thinking

Answer (score 3):

In LibreOffice 6 it is under: Page -> Properties

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice 5, it is under the `Format` → `Page/Slide Properties...` dropdown:
[image: Format Page/Slide Properties...]

This will open the `Page Setup Dialog`. Under `Paper Format`, you can choose `Format`, `Width`, `Height` and `Orientation` (Portrait/Landscape).

[image: Page Setup Paper Format Format Width Height Orientation Portrait Landscape Margins Left Right Top Bottom]

Comment: or in a sidebar